# How to keep the aspect ratio of image wrapped with <md-card>..</md-card>

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I have a block which width less than image's width inside it. This image is wrapped with angular-material's  directive:

```
<div layout="row">
  <div flex="5">
    <md-card>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/loki-dev/H400/VMZ4SlhYYaOhry1jnPaXfUKx6uU.jpeg">
    </md-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to keep the aspect ratio of that image, but this is what I get instead:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbJLXN

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your own constraints but the following code gives out what you asked:

```
 <md-card style="display:-webkit-inline-box" >
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/loki-dev/H400/VMZ4SlhYYaOhry1jnPaXfUKx6uU.jpeg">
 </md-card>
```

> inline-block elements are like inline elements but they can have a
>   width and a height. [see](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)